# Уменьшение области со сменой цвета градиента

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть переменная:

```
int liquid = 150;
```

Мне нужно, чтобы по этому принципу работала заливка.
То есть `150` это `100%`.
К примеру взяли `6` - осталось `144` - это значит `144*100/150=96%`.

Значит область заливки должна быть уже `96%`, ну я мог бы сделать это через `filAmount` у изображения и сделать по принципу `((144*100)/150)/100 = 0.96` , но к сожалению `fillAmount` - это не то, что нужно и градиент там не поддерживается и без указания на само изображение, он не будет работать.

При этом всем, мне нужно делать смену цвета, самой заливки, от яркого и постепенно менять цвет до нужного крайнего.

Кто-то сталкивался, с такой задачей?

Comment: Попробуйте [Color.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то интересно будет, сделал через `Button`.

```
float pin = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / 4, 1);
Button b = but.GetComponent<Button>();
ColorBlock cb = b.colors;
cb.normalColor = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, pin);
b.colors = cb;
b.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount = pin;
b.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = ((int)(pin * 100)).ToString() + "%";
```